# Temporary table in FROM clause instead of WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this query (which runs perfect):

```
WITH TEMPTABLE AS(
            SELECT count(CONTRACT_ID) AS no_contract, T.BRANCH_ID as branch
            FROM CONTRACT, "EMPLOYMENT" T, TABLE(T."EMPLOYEE") TT
            WHERE CONTRACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = TT.EMPLOYEE_ID
                  AND CONTRACT.CONTRACT_VT_START BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '30/06/2018'
            GROUP BY T.BRANCH_ID
        )
        SELECT branch
        FROM TEMPTABLE
        WHERE no_contract IN (SELECT MAX(no_contract)
                             FROM TEMPTABLE);
```

And I was wondering if it can be done with another way instead of WITH clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT count_per_branch.BRANCH
FROM (SELECT count(CONTRACT_ID) AS no_contract, BRANCH_ID AS BRANCH
      FROM CONTRACT, "EMPLOYMENT" T, TABLE(T."EMPLOYEE") TT
      WHERE CONTRACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = TT.EMPLOYEE_ID
            AND CONTRACT.CONTRACT_VT_START BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '30/06/2018'
      GROUP BY T.BRANCH_ID) count_per_branch
WHERE count_per_branch.no_contract =
            (SELECT max(count_per_branch.no_contract)
             FROM count_per_branch);
```

Which gives an ORA-00942: "table or view does not exist"
Error at Line: 9

Comment: The `WITH` clause creates an ad-hoc view that you can use multiple time in your query. Without the `WITH` clause, you'd have to write the subquery twice. By the way: don't use comma-separated joins. They were made redundant in 1992 in the SQL standard (and in Oracle some years later). Use proper ANSI joins instead (`FROM contract c INNER JOIN employment e ON ...`). Do you cross join the employment table on purpose? Proper joins would make this clear, but with comma joins one doesn't see if you merely forgot the join condition. And what is `TABLE(T."EMPLOYEE")` supposed to do?

Comment: Is `CONTRACT_VT_START` a string? You compare it with strings, but if you want to store dates, you should use the data type `DATE`. So either you are using the wrong data type or the wrong literals. If `CONTRACT_VT_START` is a `DATE`, then you should not compare it with strings. The DBMS would have to convert your strings implicitly, but converting them can fail, when your session is not Aware of that specific date Format. Use ANSI date literals instead: `contract_vt_start BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2018-06-30'`.

Comment: In `WHERE no_contract IN (SELECT MAX(no_contract) FROM TEMPTABLE)` you shouldn't use `IN` but `=`, because the subquery returns exactly one value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery in the FROM clause:

```
FROM (SELECT count(CONTRACT_ID) ... )
```

And you can give it an alias:

```
FROM (SELECT count(CONTRACT_ID) ... ) count_per_branch
```

And you can use that alias to qualify column references:

```
WHERE count_per_branch.no_contract =
```

But you **cannot** use that alias as a row source in another subquery, which is what you are trying to do here:

```
(SELECT max(count_per_branch.no_contract)
 FROM count_per_branch)
```

To "reuse" a subquery in this manner, you have to use the Common Table Expression syntax -- i.e., the WITH clause.